# The delay of light in the air in the experience of Michelson

Tags: special-relativity

An experiment to test the special theory of relativity was carried out in the air. Therefore, the speed of light is equal to the phase velocity of light; it is different from the speed of light in a vacuum. What will be the result of counting the delay in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a final lag. Since the phase velocity depends on the velocity of the medium, it means that the velocity of the medium can be determined, and hence the absolute velocity. The absolute speed of the medium is determined relative to infinity, on which the medium is stationary. Or it is necessary to change the definition of the Lorentz transformation, using the phase velocity instead of the speed of light in a vacuum. Each reference system has its own phase velocity of light. Then there will be no lag in the air in the experiments when testing.

I must say that the idea of using the phase velocity of light does not contain contradictions with the existing formulas. So the formula $E=mc^2$ is preserved, since the phase velocity in elementary particles is equal to the speed of light in a vacuum. The Lorentz transformation also contains the speed of light in vacuum for elementary particles, for the same reason.